# Uploading a CSV then storing the result into an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, file-upload, csv

I've been working on this problem for a few hours and have used many resources from the web and stack overflow, but I can't seem to get past this last thing. I'm in the middle of attempting to get the contents of a csv file and store them in an array and print the results on another page via a session.

index.php (Shows form for uploading file)

```
<html>
<form action="http://mysite.org/~me/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Now upload it!">
</form>
</html>
```

upload.php (if CSV, output filesize, print_r the array that should contain all data)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel"))
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
else
{
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";

    $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements
    print_r($line);
    $_SESSION['line']=$line;

}
fclose($file);

   }
 }
else
 {
 echo "Invalid file";
 }
  echo "<a href='http://mysite.org/~me/yes.php'>Yes</a>";

 ?>
```

yes.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['line'];
print_r($data);
?>
```

The print_r from the upload page should be the same as the print_r from the yes page, but it is not. It is only showing the last array. I don't understand how I would go about this problem.

As a side note: I've only been programming in php for about 2 weeks so please be thoughtful enough to explain your answers. It really helps! Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *append* instead of *overwrite* `$_SESSION['line']`.

Instead of:

```
$_SESSION['line'] = $line; // overwriting $_SESSION['line'] w/ each iteration
```

You need to:

```
$_SESSION['lines'][] = $line; // pushes the line to an array
```

Then on, *yes.php*, you can:

```
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['lines'];
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Oh! So even though $line is an array. It gets overwritten every-time the while loop runs. So, in order to append I have to create another array. Gotcha. Thanks for the clear response.